# I need data from the second table with the same classname with VBA Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, html-table, excel-2010

I want to get some data from a webpage.  I need data from two tables, but both have the same class name.

I cant get item(2) working.

I am not new to VBA, but new to Selenium.

I am able to get data from the first table, not from the second one. I search several websites, but no working solution yet.

```
Sub GetData()

Dim DRow As Byte
Dim DCol As Byte

    Dim WebDrv As New WebDriver

        Dim tr As Object
        Dim td As Object

WebDrv.Start "Chrome"
WebDrv.Get "https://stripinfo.be/reeks/strip/11316_Jeremiah_5_Het_eindeloos_experiment"

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:1")

[D7] = WebDrv.FindElementByClass("title").Text

DRow = 8
DCol = 4

For Each tr In WebDrv.FindElementByClass("innerDividers").FindElementByTag("tbody").FindElementsByTag("tr")

    For Each td In tr.FindElementsByTag("td")
        Cells(DRow, DCol).Value = td.Text
        DCol = DCol + 1
    Next td
    DRow = DRow + 1
    DCol = 4

Next tr

DRow = 15

For Each tr In WebDrv.FindElementByClass("innerDividers").FindElementByTag("tbody").FindElementsByTag("tr")

    For Each td In tr.FindElementsByTag("td")
        Cells(DRow, DCol).Value = td.Text
        DCol = DCol + 1
    Next td
    DRow = DRow + 1
    DCol = 4

Next tr

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:1")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options:

1. Change to a method returning webElements and index into the referenced collection, or use the `For Each` enumerator:

```
Dim tables As Selenium.WebElements, table As Selenium.Table, t As Long

Set tables = WebDrv.FindElementsByClass("innerDividers")

For Each table in tables
    'do something with table here

    If t = 1 Then Exit For
    t = t + 1
Next
```

2. You could also use a CSS selector list to get only those 2 tables

```
Set tables = WebDrv.FindElementsByCss("section:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(-n+3) table")
```

The latter is likely less robust over time but more efficient for a short term project.

Pick your poison.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer but it gives me an error on this line
Dim Tables As Selenium.WebElements
Set Tables = WebDrv.FindElementByClass("innerDividers") ' Runtime Error 13 : Type mismatch

Comment: you have a missing s. Look at my example.

Comment: yes indeed.  tables gived an error. now declared as object  and it works